# How to change Project Build Target to API Level 21 (in Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to usage functions that are only available in API_LEVEL = 21 (Lollipop). I'm using Eclipse here.

I go to Project Properties and then go to 'Android' - I only see the 'Android L (Preview)' in the list. I want to use 'Android 5.0 -- the API Level 21'. See below for my SDK Manager screenshot - i do have the API Level 21 files downloaded.

[image]

See below for my SDK Manager screenshot - i do have the API Level 21 files downloaded.

[image]

Comment: Have you restarted Eclipse since installing the SDK Platform for Android 5.0?

Comment: simple - use android studio..eclipse why you don't work ? :D

Comment: Did you tried by restarting eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted Eclipse and also restarted the computer. How do I get rid of the 'Android L (Preview)' and set 'Android 21' as the target?

Comment: Is there a way i can DELETE/REMOVE the 'Android L (Preview)' ???

Comment: Anyone have any ideas here? If nothing - I will need to reinstall and re-setup everything in my Eclipse Environment